# Detect whether one Turing machine invokes another

Tags: turing-machines, computability

Given two Turing machines $M,M'$, is it possible to check whether $M$ invokes $M'$?

In other words, is the following problem computable/decidable?

Inputs: Turing machines $M,M'$
Question: Does $M$ ever invoke $M'$?

Perhaps we can look whether $M$ includes the code of $M'$ in it?  In a C program we can check whether a function `f` invokes a function `g`, right?  Can we do this for Turing machines too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notion of "one machine invokes another" is ill-defined. To emphasize the point of @AbdousKamel, let us observe an even trickier example:

```
function g():
   do_something;
```

And now:

```
function f():
   k = 0
   while not "k encodes a proof of Riemann hypothesis":
     k = k + 1
   "simulate the Turing machine encoded by k"
```

In order to tell whether `f` "invokes" `g`, you have to:

1. Decide whether Riemann hypothesis is provable, and
2. Calculate whether the smallest `k` which encodes a proof of Riemann hypothesis also happens to encode a Turing machine whose behavior is equivalent to the behavior of `g`.

Question: does `f` invoke `g`?

Answer (score 0):

Following the comments of the post, i will try this example, and hope that it shows how hard it is to decide if a function `f` calls a function `g`.

Here is function `g` :

```
function g()
    do_something;
```

Here is function `f`, we will use a function called `foo` whose declaration and definition is not needed :

```
function f()
    foo();
    g();
```

Now, does `f` calls `g` ? If I look at the code of `f` I will say yes, because the call to `g` is trivially apparent. But how do I know that the call to `foo` will return ? Maybe `foo` loops forever and never halts, in this case, `f` never calls `g` because it never returns from `foo`. So deciding in a program if a function calls another needs you to decide if some pieces of programs halt, which is in fact as hard as an undecidable problem can be.

Comment: I'd like to add that if by invocation you mean that a call is present in the code, this example doesn't show anything. But if you want a call to effectively happen, you'll need to consider halting of programs.